# Why is a control not found in an updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a button in a GridView inside an UpdatePanel.

I get the following error when I run the page:

```
A control with ID 'btnShowDepend' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'TasksUpdatePanel'.
```

How do I resolve the issue.

Comment: Why you are adding triggers for that control, the control **btnShowDepend** is already in updatepanel right? is it not getting updated on click??

Comment: I am getting a fullpage update instead of just the updatepanel :/

Answer (score 2):

You better add your async trigger in the `RowDataBound` event:

```
void yourTasksGV_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton ib = e.Row.FindControl("btnShowDepend") as ImageButton;
        if (ib != null)
        {
            AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
            trigger.ControlID = ib.UniqueID;
            trigger.EventName = "Click";
            TasksUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(trigger);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a `Command` event not a `Click` event. Will that work too? I updated my question with the function for the `Command`. Please let me know if your code will still work.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: you could try :) +1.

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` I get this error on the line, `UniqueID`

Comment: please put a breakpoint after the `ImageButton` and check whether the button is null. That null reference might be triggering this error

Comment: How did you know? It is `null` and I am baffled as to WHY :/

Comment: Not every row will have the image button, I have a condition using SQL to add the image button based on query. So maybe I check for `null` before I assign the command.

Comment: I updated my question with the `RowDataBound` function. What is happening is, when the GridView first loads some of the row font color is RED. When the button is clicked, the red text turns to black and I can't seem to figure out why :/

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: and move the asynctrigger from headerrow to datarow

Answer (score 2):

```
Button btnShowDepend=(Button)TasksUpdatePanel.FindControl("btnShowDepend");
```

Please use this

Or Maybe you have to put btnShowDepend out of updatepanel

Comment: In btnShowDepend_click, you can add TasksUpdatePanel.Update();

Comment: this wont work. because the button is inside the gridview. dont try

Answer (score 2):

Add one more updatepanel within **ContentTemplate**

```html
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updButton" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <asp:ImageButton ID="btnShowDepend" runat="server" OnCommand="btnShowDepend_Command" />
</ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Not every row will have the image button, I have a condition using SQL to add the image button based on query. So maybe I check for `null` before I assign the command.

Answer (score 2):

you need to register that **Image button** as an AsyncPostbackTrigger.

Try this one in `RowDataBound`

```html
protected void yourTasksGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs 
{  
  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
   ImageButton ib = e.Row.FindControl("btnShowDepend") as ImageButton;  
   ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(ib);  
  }  
}
```

Comment: `ib` is null for some reason.

Comment: Not every row will have the image button, I have a condition using SQL to add the image button based on query. So maybe I check for `null` before I assign the command.